# Dynamically coloring a US map with Javascript

Tags: javascript, maps

I need to write a webpage which starts with a blank map of the US and colors the states according to data it receives from various Ajax requests.  The map needs to change over time without the page reloading, and the user can click on various controls to instantly change how the map is colored.  This all needs to be done locally, so I can't make use of Google maps or any similar internet service.

I'd hope to do this in the browser with Javascript.  Is there a good library for doing this?  Or any general suggestions for how to best implement this?

Comment: Can you use flash? This sounds like a great job for Flash.

Comment: Unfortunately Flash isn't an option.  It's possible that Java Applets might be permissible, but the client won't have Flash installed in many of their browsers, which makes it a non-starter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would take a plugin like this just change it to do "highlighting" based on your dynamic data:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight
- Demo of plugin: http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

Currently it highlights on mouseover, but highlighting using data given should be very straightforward.

The fact it comes with a map of the US and highlighting ready to go set is just gravy.

Comment: The links are not working. Is this the same plugin: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Highlighting-Image-Map-Maphilight.html?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is example of pure JS, SVG/VML solution: http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

Answer (score 1):

You may still be able to use the Google Static Maps API's "path" parameter to overlay the color you want. Create some static maps and save the resulting image.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html#Paths

Comment: spiffy! I haven't heard about this before but it seems like a great tool for some applications I have in mind.